# Should throw invoke the move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does an exception use move semantics when thrown in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122317/does-an-exception-use-move-semantics-when-thrown-in-c11)

I'm wondering why the move constructor is not invoked by `throw` when appropriate. Is this a defect in my compiler (Visual Studio 2010/2012) or is it simply not allowed by the standard? In the latter case, what would the reasoning be?

The following is an example where I'd expect the move constructor to be invoked, but the copy constructor is used instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class MyException : public std::exception
{
public:
    MyException(const char* theText) throw()
    :   std::exception(theText) {
        try { std::cout << "MyException()" << std::endl; } catch(...) {}
    }

    ~MyException() throw() {
        try { std::cout << "~MyException()" << std::endl; } catch(...) {}
    }

    MyException(const MyException& ex) throw() 
    :   std::exception(ex) {
        try { std::cout << "MyException copy constructor" << std::endl; } catch (...) {}
    }

    MyException& operator=(const MyException& ex) throw() {
        try { std::cout << "MyException assignment operator" << std::endl; } catch (...) {}
        std::exception::operator=(ex);
        return *this;
    }

    MyException(MyException&& ex) throw()
    :   std::exception(std::move(ex)) {
        try { std::cout << "MyException move constructor" << std::endl; } catch (...) {}
    }

    MyException& operator=(MyException&& ex) throw() {
        try { std::cout << "MyException move assignment operator" << std::endl; } catch (...) {}
        std::exception::operator=(std::move(ex));
        return *this;
    }
};



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        //throw MyException("RVO applies here");

        MyException e("Let's try explicitly");
        throw std::move(e); // The copy constructor is called
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught std::exception " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This prints the following

```
MyException()
MyException copy constructor
~MyException()
Caught std::exception Let's try explicitly
~MyException()
```

Comment: Fwiw you dont need std::move. not using it makes the compiler free to elide the move altogether even if it has side effects.

Comment: The "possible duplicate" question seems to answer my headline with a "yes". Meaning that VS2012 gets this wrong. Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: I ran into the same thing yesterday. Confused the hell out of me. Yes VS2012 invokes the copy-constructor. Even if it's private.