# Can not-copyable class be caught by value in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, initialization, language-lawyer, copy-initialization

In the next program, struct `B` with deleted copy-constructor is thrown and caught by value:

```
struct B {
    B() = default;
    B(const B&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    try {
        throw B{};
    }
    catch( B ) {
    }
}
```

Clang rejects the code with an expected error:

```
error: call to deleted constructor of 'B'
    catch( B ) {
```

However GCC accepts the program finely, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ed45YKKo5

Which compiler is right here?

Comment: The GCC example you have written also reject your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122317/does-an-exception-use-move-semantics-when-thrown-in-c11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Clang is correct. (Thanks for @NathanOliver's comments.)

[[except.throw]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/except#throw-3)

> Throwing an exception copy-initializes ([dcl.init], [class.copy.ctor]) a temporary object, called the exception object. An lvalue denoting the temporary is used to initialize the variable declared in the matching handler ([except.handle]).

[[except.throw]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/except#throw-5)

> When the thrown object is a class object, the constructor selected for the copy-initialization as well as the constructor selected for a copy-initialization considering the thrown object as an lvalue shall be non-deleted and accessible, even if the copy/move operation is elided ([class.copy.elision]).

The exception object is considered as an lvalue, in the copy-initialization of the parameter of the catch clause, the copy constructor is selected. The copy operation might be elided as an optimization; but the copy constructor still has to be present and accessible.

*I've reported this as [gcc bug 103048](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=103048).*

BTW the [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) of the exception object caused by `throw B{};` is fine because of [mandatory copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (since C++17).

> In the initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type:
>
> ```
> T x = T(T(f())); // only one call to default constructor of T, to initialize x
> ```

> First, if T is a class type and the initializer is a [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) expression whose cv-unqualified type is the same class as T, the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object: see [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (since C++17)

Comment: Why am I only the second upvoter?

Comment: I'm pretty sure mandatory copy elision does not apply here.  If we look at exception throwing, the object that is being copied initialized from is an lvalue: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/except#throw-3

Comment: Also see paragraph 5 which calls out that the constructors must be accessible if it is optimized: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/except#throw-5

Comment: @Bathsheba because the end of the answer (about copy elision) is hard to read and not convincing